Older movie title-home invasion type
I'm looking for the title to an old movie where a father, daughter, & son try to fight off home invaders that are looking for a disc. The father has hidden the disc in the home's library, maybe inside a book? I remember the boy climbing through secret passages in the walls for one room to another. Also a scene where the men have the daughter out by a pool. I think the home also has a safe room that the kids are in near the end of the movie while one of the invaders dies in a fire outside the room. The house was like a fortress, with security cameras everywhere and I think metal covers over the windows. The Dad is into something bad, so he has extra security measures on the house.

This would be Hostage starring Bruce Willis as a police negotiator.  A group of teenagers break into a house to steal stuff and the son runs around the house in hidden passage ways.  Ben Foster's character takes things a lot further than the other two wanted to.

That's it, thank you for your help identifying this title!
